# Regular expression to match only domain from URL

Tags: regex

I'm struggling with forming a regex that would match:

1. Just domain in case of URL
2. Whole string in case of no URL

Acceptance test (regex should match bold text):

- http://**mozart.co.uk**
- https://**avocado.si/hmm**
- http://www.**qwe123qwe.com**
- **Starbucks**
- **Benchmark 123**

So far I've come up with this:

```
([^\/\/]+)(?:,|$)
```

It works fine, but not for URLs with trailing slash on the end. How can I modify the expression to include full path (everything on the right side of http(s)://) as well? Thank you.

Comment: Your regex as stated `([^\/\/]+)(?:,|$)` matches any string with an even number of non-slash characters ended with a comma or the end of the string. I don't think it's quite as close as you thought it was...

Comment: I'm unclear - do you want the domain or the remainder of the URL? In https://avacado.si/hmm you have included `/hmm` which is not part of the domain.

Comment: I should add I need to use this regex in combination with Postgres's ordering by substring, like this: "order by substring(column, regex)", so this regex should match only one group, and I also don't have any URL parsing utilities here.

Comment: @PeterBowers I made a mistake in the title, actually I need to match everything on the right side of "http(s)://", as well as normal non-url strings too.

Answer (score 1):

This regex will match them if it starts with http:// or https:// until the next slash. If it doesn't start with http:// nor https:// then it will match the whole string. Close enough?

```
(?:^https?:\/\/([^\/]+)(?:[\/,]|$)|^(.*)$)
```

I should note that most languages have functions built in to properly parse URLs and these are preferable.

You should note that I've got 2 sets of capturing parentheses, so depending on your language that may be significant.

Comment: This matches only the domain, not the path after the domain. Your specs above were ambiguous (i.e., description didn't match example) so I've gone with your description.

Comment: Please note my reply to your comment under my question. Due to the nature of languge I need a regex that extracts only one matching group.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that `^(http[s]?:\/\/)?(.*)$`. Play here: https://regex101.com/r/iZ2vL4/1

Answer (score 0):

This will have Matching groups, the domain you want will be in the 4th matching group.

```
/^((http[s]?|ftp):\/\/)?\/?([^\/\.]+\.)*?([^\/\.]+\.[^:\/\s\.]{1,3}(\.[^:\/\s\.]{1,2})?(:\d+)?)($|\/)([^#?\s]+)?(.*?)?(#[\w\-]+)?$/mg
```

[Regex101.com workbench to check out your URLs](https://regex101.com/r/kI0cKH/1) just paste them in the "TEST STRING" Textbox to test it out.

Don't recall where I got this... so I don't know who to credit. But it's pretty slick!